# Retrieving a value from a parameter of an object in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, parameters, get, arraylist

Let's say I have an array list of objects, and each object has the Parameters:

```
Object(String string, int x, int y)
```

How would I get only the string parameter at the given index? I hope I'm not being too broad here..
I only want to retrieve the `String` parameter from the `Object` at the specified index in my `ArrayList`.

Comment: `list.get(42).getString()`? You **are** overly broad, show us more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generic ArrayLists if at all possible and simply call your object's getter method for the field whose value you wish to obtain. Otherwise if you can't use a generic ArrayList, you'll have to cast the object returned to the type it should be before calling the getter (accessor) method.

e.g. assuming a getter method of `getString()`,

```
myArrayList.get(3).getString();
```

if not generic you'll have to cast to your object's class:

```
((MyClass)myArrayList.get(3)).getString();
```

Comment: I hate to be a bother and sound like an idiot. But, I am only in beginner's Java and I am already not learning well, sadly. I have a toString() method that displays the summary of the objects. I just can't grasp my mind around pulling only the String parameter...

Answer (score 0):

If the object has a corresponding `get` method for the `String` parameter, you could use reflection for retrieving its value (if you don't know the name of the attribute) or simply call it by name if you *do* now its name, like this: `list.get(index).getStringAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You do just like you would in any other collection

say you have objects `alist[o1,o2,o3]` in your `ArrayList`, and you want `o2.String`

you'd go `alist.get(1).getString() // or whatever your getter is to obtain the string`

Comment: What if I have no getter to obtain the String?

Comment: What Hovercraft Full of EEls said. You could of course go with a public final property instead, but the point is that it should be retrievable without using any fancy reflection techniques or the like.